# Нужно ли пословицы брать в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, пословицы

Есть одна очень хорошая пословица: «Если тебе трудно — значит, ты на верном пути».

Comment: Думаю, это пословица, а не поговорка. См: [Чем отличаются пословицы и поговорки](https://chtoby-pravilno.ru/poslovicy-pogovorki/)

Comment: Думаю, это и не пословица, максимум — "как кто-то сказал".

Comment: Афоризм это, полагаю.

Comment: @Сашка-дурак, Возможно, афоризм. Раньше мне такая фраза не встречалась. А может, иностранная пословица? В любом случае надо бы что-то пояснить читателю.

Comment: Посмотрел: фраза гуляет по интернету. Точно афоризм!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, это пословица, а не поговорка. См: [Чем отличаются пословицы и поговорки](https://chtoby-pravilno.ru/poslovicy-pogovorki/)

Корректно:
**Есть одна очень хорошая пословица: «Если тебе трудно — значит, ты на верном пути».**

Обычно пословицы пишутся в кавычках, их можно приравнять к цитатам.

Однако у Розенталя находим [замечание](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154), которое может заставить нас призадуматься:

> 2. Не выделяется кавычками прямая речь в следующих случаях:
>      1) если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, или если приводится общеизвестная пословица, поговорка:
>
> Дома и хворать легче и жить дешевле; и недаром говорится: дома и стены помогают (Ч.);

Но в данном случае у нас пословица не очень известная и она вводится словом *пословица*, поэтому замечание Розенталя не работает.

Возникает также вопрос о постановке двоеточия. И опять Розенталь заставляет сомневаться:

> [Примечание](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159). Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
>
> Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.); Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», всё больше собирало сторонников (Ф.); Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

И вновь проходим к выводу, что данное примечание в нашем случае не работает.

Дополнение. Эта фраза с небольшими вариациями гуляет по интернету, но нигде нет намека на то, что это пословица. Скорее всего, нужно считать ее афоризмом (спасибо, @Сашка-дурак, за подсказку). Oднако на постановку двоеточия и кавычек это не влияет:

**Есть один очень хороший афоризм: «Если тебе трудно — значит, ты на верном пути».**